# DataGridView: Change Edit Control size while editing

Tags: c#, datagridview, edit

in the *DataGridView* I want the cell size to expand according to the string length when I edit the cell. Excel does the same.

In the *DataGridView*, when entering edit mode, a *DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl* is placed at the cell position. I tried to change the bounds/size of this control, but result is just a short flicker of my desired size. It gets directly overpainted the original, truncated way.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Thanks,

Timo

Answer (score 3):

You need to start by overriding the [DataGridViewCell.PositionEditingPanel Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.positioneditingpanel.aspx). You need to redefine your own type of column and your own type of cell to access this method.

Here is an example on how to do it, that multiply the size of the editing panel (the one that owns the editing control) by 2:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false; // disable columns auto generation

... add all columns

// add your special column
col = new MyColumn();
col.DataPropertyName = "Text"; // bind with the corresponding property
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col); // add the custom column

... add other columns

public class MyCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public override Rectangle PositionEditingPanel(Rectangle cellBounds, Rectangle cellClip, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, bool singleVerticalBorderAdded, bool singleHorizontalBorderAdded, bool isFirstDisplayedColumn, bool isFirstDisplayedRow)
    {
        cellBounds.Width *= 2;
        cellClip.Width = cellBounds.Width;
        return base.PositionEditingPanel(cellBounds, cellClip, cellStyle, singleVerticalBorderAdded, singleHorizontalBorderAdded, isFirstDisplayedColumn, isFirstDisplayedRow);
    }
}

public class MyColumn : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    public MyColumn()
    {
        CellTemplate = new MyCell();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is quite old but hopefully my answer helps somebody down the road.  I ran across the same problem and was able to use a process similar to the following to make the column width update dynamically as the user typed, in order to ensure the text fit in the column.

Events used:

- `CellBeginEdit`
- `CellEndEdit`
- `EditingControlShowing`
- `TextBoxKeyPressEvent` (i.e. `KeyPress`)

**NOTE:** The following code assumes that `AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells`

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Copies the original column width because switching to DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None
    // will automatically make the column a default width.
    int origColumnWidth = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;

    dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;

    // Reverts back to the original width.
    dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width = origColumnWidth;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is TextBox)
    {
        var tbox = (e.Control as TextBox);

        // De-register the event FIRST so as to avoid multiple assignments (necessary to do this or the event
        // will be called +1 more time each time it's called).
        tbox.KeyPress -= TextBoxKeyPressEvent;
        tbox.KeyPress += TextBoxKeyPressEvent;
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

private void TextBoxKeyPressEvent(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Gets the text prior to the new character being added.  Appending an arbitrary "0" to the value
    // to account for the missing character when determining appropriate measurements.
    string prevText = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString() + "0";

    Graphics editControlGraphics = dataGridView1.EditingControl.CreateGraphics();

    // Gets the length of the current text value.
    SizeF stringSize = editControlGraphics.MeasureString(prevText, dataGridView1.EditingControl.Font);

    int widthForString = (int)Math.Round(stringSize.Width, 0);

    // Makes the column width big enough if it's not already.
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Width < widthForString)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Width = widthForString;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Update to the `TextBoxKeyPressEvent` logic to account for Backspace:

```
private void TextBoxKeyPressEvent(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            string prevText;
            bool wasBackspaced = false;

            // The following logic will either add or remove a character to/from the text string depending if the user typed
            // an additional character or pressed the Backspace key.  At the end of the day, the cell will (at least) be
            // sized to the configured minimum column width or the largest row width in the column because we're using 
            // AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells.
            if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back))
            {
                prevText = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();

                if (prevText.Length == 0)
                {
                    // Don't try to make it any smaller...
                    return;
                }

                // Remove an arbitrary character for determining appropriate measurements.
                prevText = prevText.Remove(prevText.Length - 1);
                wasBackspaced = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Gets the text prior to the new character being added.  Appending an arbitrary "0" to the value
                // to account for the missing character when determining appropriate measurements.
                prevText = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString() + "0";
            }

            Graphics editControlGraphics = dataGridView1.EditingControl.CreateGraphics();

            // Gets the length of the current text value.
            SizeF stringSize = editControlGraphics.MeasureString(prevText, dataGridView1.EditingControl.Font);

            int widthForString = (int)Math.Round(stringSize.Width, 0);

            // Makes the column width big, or small, enough if it's not already.
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Width < widthForString ||  // 1. Applies when adding text
                (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Width > widthForString &&          // ---
                 dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.MinimumWidth < widthForString &&   // 2. Applies when backspacing
                 wasBackspaced))                                                           // ---
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Width = widthForString;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This has a few problems(a,b,c).    **a)** it only expands and doesn't shrink, e.g. if I backdelete characters it doesn't shrink and should really  **b)** if I backdelete within the cell, then that code doesn't work, it treats backdelete like any regular character and expands the cell one character, when i'd want it to shrink the cell.   **c)** If I hit forward delete, then the procedure TextBoxKeyPressEvent  doesn't even trigger. So it won't try to shrink the textbox.

Comment: @barlop You were correct that my original example didn't take the Backspace key into account.  I've updated my post with additional code of how that could be handled. I was originally banking on the fact that the control would automatically resize the column based on the minimum width property and the AutoSizeColumnsMode being set to "AllCells," but this only happens after the edit is committed.  As per point C, you're right, the Delete key would have to be caught using the KeyDown event.  Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188328/c-sharp-keypress-doesnt-capture-delete-key

Comment: ok... another thing that may be worth correcting is that   using `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue` is perhaps a bit risky,  as mentioned here this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207777/datagridview-cell-turns-black-when-accessing-editedformattedvalue    perhaps better to use `dataGridView1.EditingControl.Text`

Answer (score 0):

This was work for me:

Enable `KeyPreview` Property of the form and change the body of `KeyPress` Event of the form to this:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.KeyChar!='\b')   //discard backspace
            {
              dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width += 5;  //the column's index or name

            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width -= 5;  //for backspase pressing
            }
}
```

you can limit the pressed keys with `e.KeyChar` ;

Comment: though then even when the cell is empty  or when the cursor is on the far left, and the person is hitting backdelete, the cell(and thus perhaps the whole column), is shrinking. It shouldn't really shrink if backdelete isn't deleting a character

Answer (score 0):

I have found a few solutions for this

One uses MeasureString and one datagridview ,  another creates another datagridview for the purposes of figuring out the correct width of a cell if the cell were to have that content. Another(my latest one) manages it with one datagridview and adding and removing a row.

This is the one that uses  a second datagridview

Draw a datagridview on a form  i've given mine two columns no data.

The code will create a second datagridview also with two columns no data.

Of course the issue that the questioner ran into was that without the editing automatically autosizing, it's not clear what width to set the column. This solution creates another datagridview (call it DGVb), this one not added to the form. And it writes that data to a cell in DGVb, sees what width the cell took, and uses that figure as the figure to set the cell in the proper DGV.

Another issue covered by vine, is that with the cell set to autosize, you can't set the column's width programmatically,  so you can put code on when the cellbeginedit event is triggered, to set autosize to none, and put it back on when cellendedit is triggered, and another thing is that because setting to none might immediately change the column size a bit e.g. column1 with autosize on might be 73 and then when you turn autosize off it goes to 100, so you can store the size before you put autosize to none, then put autosize to none and set the size to what it was, that way preserving that unwanted size change.  That is what is done here, as covered by Vine.

this code expands and shrinks the column and doesn't have weaknesses with backdelete, forward delete or arrow keys, though as of writing, vine's answer has some weaknesses with those keys.   I have used TextChanged to avoid those problems. (as opposed to keydown e.t.c.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace datagridviewexpandcelldynamically_with_second_dgv
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dgvtest = new DataGridView();
        //  DataGridView dgvtest;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                dgvtest.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

                dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += (object ssender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs ee) =>
                {
                    //keep column width as it is for now but just change autosize to none so will be able to manually increase it
                    int origColumnWidth = dataGridView1.Columns[ee.ColumnIndex].Width;
                    dataGridView1.Columns[ee.ColumnIndex].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
                    dataGridView1.Columns[ee.ColumnIndex].Width = origColumnWidth;
                };

                dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += (object sssender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs eee) =>
                {
                    dataGridView1.Columns[eee.ColumnIndex].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                };

                dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
                dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

                dgvtest.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
                dgvtest.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;


                dgvtest.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column1");
                dgvtest.Columns.Add("Column2", "Column2");

                dgvtest.Rows.Add(1);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);

                /*
                Form newfrm = new Form();
                newfrm.Show();
                newfrm.Controls.Add(dgvtest);
                dgvtest.Show();
                */

                //dgvtest.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "abc";


        }



        private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Control is TextBox)
            {
                var tbox = (e.Control as TextBox);

                // De-register the event FIRST so as to avoid multiple assignments (necessary to do this or the event
                // will be called +1 more time each time it's called).

                tbox.TextChanged -= TextBoxChanged;
                tbox.TextChanged += TextBoxChanged;
                //not KeyDown 'cos the character has not appeared yet in the box. and one would have to check what it was as a parameter, and if it's a backdelete then go back one.. and also forward delete isn't coutned as a keydown.
                //not KeyUp 'cos while yeah the character has at least appeared, there's a delay so if you hold backdelete then only after releasing it will it trigger the procedure, and updating the width of the cell then is a bit late.
                //not KeyPress 'cos has issues of keyup. 

            }

        }


        private void TextBoxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            int colindex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;


            int oldcolwidth = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Size.Width;
            //string stredit=dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
            string stredit=dataGridView1.EditingControl.Text;
            dgvtest.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = stredit;

            int newcolwidth = dgvtest.Rows[0].Cells[0].Size.Width;

            int headercellsize = dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].HeaderCell.Size.Width;

            // find biggest existing one
            int maxcellincol = headercellsize;

            int tempcelllength = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[colindex].Value == null) dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[colindex].Value = "";

                //length of all others but not current.
                tempcelllength = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[colindex].Size.Width;

                if (tempcelllength > maxcellincol) maxcellincol = tempcelllength;
            }



            int diffcol = newcolwidth - oldcolwidth;

            // new isn't an ideal name.. 'cos it's not made new yet.. and 'cos if it's smaller than the max one then we won't make it the new one.. but it will be the new one if it's bigger than the max.

            // txtdesc.Text = "";
            txtdesc.Text += "newcolwidth=" + newcolwidth + "\r\n";
            txtdesc.Text += "maxcellincol=" + maxcellincol + "\r\n";


            //if (newcolwidth < maxcellincol)  != even if = then fine.

            dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width = newcolwidth;
            dataGridView1.Width += diffcol;

        } 

    }


}
```

The idea of expanding the cell as text is being typed is quite a hack.. but seems visually preferable to this alternative.. which is less tricky to do but doesn't look as nice, that is, to just have the cell expand in size on cellbeginedit, (so set to autosize to none, and set col width to some size like =50), and have it shrink back to size - autosize - on cellendedit) and then i suppose on cellendedit to increase datagridview width so it doesn't get a scroll bar. But then the datagridview col jumps in size and it's not nice to use.

Comment: this could be improved a bit if it were possible to somehow clone the datagridview, or alternatively perhaps the next best thing is to copy the values with the font(s), since the width of a cell depends on all the other cells in the column, their data and font.  This one works becaues the second datagridview has the same data as the first.

Comment: actually probably the second datagridview only requires 2 cells.. one to hold the max of that col from the first datagridview , the other to have the value of the cell in the first datagridview that is being edited. And the fonts can be set to be those of the corresponding cells on the first datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned in my other answer that I had two solutions, this one is the MeasureString solution (as opposed to the second datagridview solution)

any mention of textbox1-5.text e.t.c. has been commented it was just for debugging.

this, and the other solution, doesn't just resize the column you are editting in, it also resizes datagridview's width, and the form width, though you can easily comment that if you don't want that behaviour.

I should probably have used the 'uses' keyword for creating the graphics object, but anyhow.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace datagridviewexpandcelldynamically
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {

            int origColumnWidth = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;

            dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;

            dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width = origColumnWidth;

            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == null) dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "";


        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Control is TextBox)
            {
                var tbox = (e.Control as TextBox);

                // De-register the event FIRST so as to avoid multiple assignments (necessary to do this or the event
                // will be called +1 more time each time it's called).

                tbox.TextChanged -= TextBoxChanged;
                tbox.TextChanged += TextBoxChanged;

            }

        }

        private void TextBoxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // try catch is helpful in a winforms program 'cos otherwise program might just stop.
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583351/silent-failures-in-c-seemingly-unhandled-exceptions-that-does-not-crash-the-pr

            try
            {
                int colindex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

                Graphics agraphics = this.CreateGraphics();

                SizeF headerTextSize = agraphics.MeasureString(dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].HeaderText, dataGridView1.EditingControl.Font);

                // sometimes it goes black and this link here says to use editing control http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207777/datagridview-cell-turns-black-when-accessing-editedformattedvalue

                // string stredit=dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
                string stredit=myDataGridView.EditingControl.Text;
                SizeF curCellTextSize = agraphics.MeasureString(stredit, dataGridView1.EditingControl.Font);
                //SizeF curCellTextSize = agraphics.MeasureString(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.GetEditedFormattedValue.ToString(), dataGridView1.EditingControl.Font);
                int curCellTextSize_i = (int)Math.Round(curCellTextSize.Width, 0);

                int headerCellSize = dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width;

                textBox2.Text = headerTextSize.Width.ToString();
                textBox3.Text = headerCellSize.ToString();

                // find biggest existing one
                int maxcelltextincol = (int)Math.Round(headerTextSize.Width,0);
                // the max size, at least for the header, includes a bit of padding.. 
                maxcelltextincol += 20;
                int tempcelllength=0;
                for(int i=0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++) {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[colindex].Value == null) dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[colindex].Value = "";

                    tempcelllength = (int)Math.Round(agraphics.MeasureString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[colindex].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.EditingControl.Font).Width, 0);

                    if (tempcelllength > maxcelltextincol) maxcelltextincol = tempcelllength;       
                }


            //    textBox2.Text = "PRE curCellTextSize_i=" + curCellTextSize_i + " " + "dgvw=" + dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width.ToString() + " max=" + maxcelltextincol.ToString() +  " prevstringlength=";

                string txtinwhatiamediting = stredit;

                SizeF sizelengthoftxtinwhatiamediting = agraphics.MeasureString(txtinwhatiamediting, dataGridView1.Font); //intermediate
                int lengthoftxtinwhatiamediting=(int)Math.Round(sizelengthoftxtinwhatiamediting.Width,0);

                //if(lengthoftxtinwhatiamediting>maxcelltextincol) 
                int amountovermax = lengthoftxtinwhatiamediting - maxcelltextincol;    


                int oldcolwidth = dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width;
                if (amountovermax < 0) { dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width = maxcelltextincol; return; }


                dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width = maxcelltextincol + amountovermax;
                int newcolwidth = dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width;
                   //dataGridView1.Width += (int)Math.Round((double)amountovermax,0);
                dataGridView1.Width += newcolwidth - oldcolwidth;
                this.Width += newcolwidth - oldcolwidth;
                //   textBox2.Text = "curCellTextSize_i=" + curCellTextSize_i + " " + "dgvw=" + dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width.ToString() + " max=" + maxcellincol.ToString();

                if (curCellTextSize_i > maxcelltextincol) maxcelltextincol = curCellTextSize_i;

                  // textBox5.Text= "POST curCellTextSize_i=" + curCellTextSize_i + " " + "dgvw=" + dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width.ToString() + " max=" + maxcelltextincol.ToString() + "prevstring=" + prevString + " prevstringlength=" + prevtextsize + " diff=" + diff;
                 //  textBox5.Text = "POST curCellTextSize_i=" + curCellTextSize_i + " " + "dgvw=" + dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width.ToString() + " max=" + maxcelltextincol.ToString() + " diff=" + amountovermax;


            }
            catch (Exception ee) { MessageBox.Show(ee.ToString()); }                                
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                dataGridView1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("David", 30.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);

                dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
                dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;                

                Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics(); // should be in a using.

                Font fontA = new System.Drawing.Font("David", 30.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

                SizeF headerSize = g.MeasureString(dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText, fontA);

                int totalcolwidth = dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth + 40; // about 40+70
                //MessageBox.Show(totalcolwidth.ToString());
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                    totalcolwidth += dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width;

              //  MessageBox.Show(totalcolwidth.ToString());
              //  MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Width.ToString());
                int diff = totalcolwidth - dataGridView1.Width;
                dataGridView1.Width = totalcolwidth;
              //  MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Width.ToString());
                this.Width += diff;

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("exception ");
                MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution(my latest) uses a similar technique to the answer that uses 2 datagridviews, but it manages it with just one datagridview.

What it does is when text is typed into a cell, it creates a new row, and enters that text into that row at the corresponding column within that row. Then it sees what the new width should be and it expands the column to that width and removes that row.

It's an edit of what I had, that improves it.. Since it turned out that I could comment out the cellbeginedit and cellendedit method.  And it also found that while the previous one was fine, a slight amendment would cause the bug of a black cell, and that is mentioned here. As long as i'm autosizing all columns I avoid the black cell. (that and using EditingControl.Text as I have)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace dgveditresize
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //DGVprocs.dgv = dataGridView1;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

            autoshrinkwholedgv();

            //DGVprocs.autoshrink_off_wholedgv__preservewidths(); not necessary
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(5);
            //dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += OnCellBeginEditExpandCol;

             dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;

          //  MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width.ToString());
        }


        private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {

           // MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width.ToString());



            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505883/how-can-i-dynamically-detect-the-characters-in-a-datagridview-cell-execute-co

            //if(DGVprocs.isshrinkon()==false) { MessageBox.Show("err ")}

            if (e.Control is TextBox)
            {
                var tbox = (e.Control as TextBox);

                // De-register the event FIRST so as to avoid multiple assignments (necessary to do this or the event
                // will be called +1 more time each time it's called).

                tbox.TextChanged -= A_Cell_TextChanged;
                tbox.TextChanged += A_Cell_TextChanged;
            }



        }

        private void A_Cell_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);

            //MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows.Count+" rows");

            int colindex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;


            int oldcolwidth = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Size.Width;
            //string stredit=dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
            string stredit = dataGridView1.EditingControl.Text;

            //dgvtest.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = stredit;
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value = stredit;
            //MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows.Count + " rows");
            //int newcolwidth = dgvtest.Rows[0].Cells[0].Size.Width;

            //autoshrinkcurrentcol(); // WORSE   (1)  WW
            autoshrinkwholedgv(); //added BETTER (2)  XX
            int newcolwidth = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Size.Width;
            autoshrinkoff_wholedgv_preservewidths(); //added BETTER (3) YY
           // autoshrink_off_currentcol_preservewidth(); // WORSE (4)  ZZ
             /*               
             WAS ERROR WITH THIS ONE..
             IF YOU TYPE IN THE FIRST CELL THEN HIT DOWN ARROW TWICE
             THEN TYPE THEN IT GOES BLACK
             BUT PROBLEM RESOLVED  SINCE USING 2,3 RATHER THAN 1,4                    
              */
            // doing either  1,4  or 2,3
            // no comparison
            // 1,4 causes blackness.
            // 2,3 and it works
            // all of them is just same as 2,3 not surprising.
            // but funny that 1,4 causes blackness.


            //MessageBox.Show("removing row");

            if(dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows) { MessageBox.Show("programmer msg- issue in 'cell's textchanged method', allowusertoaddrows must be false otherwise an exception is thrown by the next line dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1);"); Application.Exit(); }
                // requires user not add row set to true.
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1);

            //MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows.Count + " rows");

            int headercellsize = dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].HeaderCell.Size.Width;

            // find biggest existing one
            int maxcellincol = headercellsize;

            int tempcelllength = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[colindex].Value == null) dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[colindex].Value = "";

                //length of all others but not current.
                tempcelllength = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[colindex].Size.Width;

                if (tempcelllength > maxcellincol) maxcellincol = tempcelllength;
            }



            int diffcol = newcolwidth - oldcolwidth;

            // new isn't an ideal name.. 'cos it's not made new yet.. and 'cos if it's smaller than the max one then we won't make it the new one.. but it will be the new one if it's bigger than the max.

             txtdesc.Text = "";
            txtdesc.Text += "newcolwidth=" + newcolwidth + "\r\n";
            txtdesc.Text += "maxcellincol=" + maxcellincol + "\r\n";


            //if (newcolwidth < maxcellincol)  != even if = then fine.

            // say we move that earlier
            //dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1);

            //DGVprocs.autoshrinkoff_preservecurrentcolwidth();


            //if (dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width == newcolwidth)
            if (oldcolwidth == newcolwidth)
            txtwidthcomp.Text="old width is equal to cur width diff="+diffcol;
            else
                txtwidthcomp.Text="old width is not equal to cur width diff="+diffcol;

            //shrink should never be on while there's an editbox showing.
            //if (diffcol>0) if (DGVprocs.isshrinkon() == true) MessageBox.Show("shrink is on this may be why it's not resizing");
            // when turning autoshrink off a)it should be done after the editbox it will freeze the editbox to the size that it was. b)when it is done it should be done in a preservational way. getting all col sizes beforehand and turning shrink off and setting all cols to that size that they were 
            // DGVprocs.autoshrinkoff();
            // shrink has to be off for the current column.. doesn't matter about the rest of it.
            // if(diffcol>0) if(DGVprocs.isshrinkoncurrentcol()==true) MessageBox.Show("shrink is on(cur col) this may be why it's not resizing");



            dataGridView1.Columns[colindex].Width = newcolwidth;
            dataGridView1.Width += diffcol;


            // i think autoshrink while the editbox is showing is wrong.
            // you need to autoshrink it to size of editbox.
//            DGVprocs.autoshrink();


        }


        public void autoshrinkwholedgv()
        {

            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

            return;
        }

        public void autoshrinkcurrentcol()
        {

            dataGridView1.Columns[getcurrentcol()].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;

            //this may be optional.
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

            // DGVprocs.dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

            return;
        }

        public int getcurrentcol()
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == null) { MessageBox.Show("Programmer msg - getcurrentcol() error, current cell not selected"); Application.Exit(); }
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == null) dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "";

            return dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        }

        public void autoshrink_off_currentcol_preservewidth()
        {
            int w =  dataGridView1.Columns[getcurrentcol()].Width;
            dataGridView1.Columns[getcurrentcol()].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            dataGridView1.Columns[getcurrentcol()].Width = w;
        }

        public void autoshrinkoff_wholedgv_preservewidths()
        {
            // deal with the 73,100 bug.. whereby if you ave autoresize on immediately, then a DGV with Column1 Colum2, Column3 e.t.c. has width of 73. But then when turning autoresize off it goes to 100. 

            int[] colsizes = new int[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                colsizes[i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width;

            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = colsizes[i];


            return;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: the above does not seem to get the black cell problem though a slight modification to the code to use lines WW and ZZ would cause it. That looks like a bug with the datagridview and is mentioned here  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2878864/datagridview-cell-goes-black   and a similar bug is mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207777/datagridview-cell-turns-black-when-accessing-editedformattedvalue

Answer (score -1):

Would you like the cell to resize as you type? Or would you like it to resize once the text is entered and enter is hit? The second option is by fair the easiest.

Let me know.

Thanks

Comment: -1 Instead of asking another question, you probably should just give the answer to both ways you describe or make this a comment on the question.