# Silent failures in C#, seemingly unhandled exceptions that does not crash the program

Tags: c#, winforms, 64-bit, exception

In a winforms app, in a form's Load event, add the following line:

```
throw new Exception();
```

and run the application. It ran without a problem. This is called a silent failure, you can try to add messageboxes before and after, and you'll soon find out that instead of crashing the application, the throw statement just exits from the Load event.

I'm sure there is no need to explain how ugly and dangerous this is.

I was wondering nonetheless in the (probably history) reasons behind this terrifying behavior.
I'm sure it's not a design decision, probably no-choice, or laziness. Does anybody know?

Would be glad if anyone can point me to a list of events which may cause seilent failures too.

Here's a snippet of my code - I have no idea how it might help - but, here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Form f = new Form();
            f.Load += new EventHandler((x, y) => { throw new Exception(); });
            Application.Run(f);
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**
It seems it does not happend to everyone.
I use: fw 3.5, winforms, vs 2008, vista x64, new clean project of winforms, with the code mentioned above.

Comment: Can you further explain your problem with a snippet from your OnLoad event handler for your form.  

Also, do you have an UnhandledException handler within this application domain?  If this is the main form of the application and it can't load because you threw an unhandled exception what did you expect to have happen?  I suspect your the unhandled event handler would be invoked in this case.

Comment: What version of windows are you using?

Comment: I actually voted your previous question down again, it's badly written AND arrogant...

Comment: Your question is not answered here: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/20/how-to-not-get-a-question-answered.aspx

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is a [known problem on x64 systems](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=325742):

> This is a known issue on 64-bit OS
>   platform. The reason is that the 64bit
>   OS core does not allow user mode
>   exception through kernal mode stacks.
>   The exception is swallowed by OS
>   sliently. That happens in FormLoad
>   handler, because it is called in an OS
>   callback. 32bits OS doesn't do this,
>   so it doesn't repro there.
>
> The OS team is investigating related
>   issues. In the mean time, you do have
>   to work around this issue. Turning on
>   "Stop on first chance exception" will
>   make the debugger to stop in this
>   scenario. But it does make the
>   debugger to stop very often, so you
>   might want to do this only when you
>   find a problem.

The linked bug report was last updated February 2008, and doesn't indicate what's happened since then.

I can reproduce most poster's behavior on my 32-bit system here, and I can reproduce the OP's behavior on my 64-bit (Vista SP2, 3.5SP1 Framework) work PC.

Comment: thanks a lot.. i half remember this happened to me as well with x86, but i'm not sure enough.. i'll check it out.

Comment: Interestingly, this exception is not swallowed on my Windows 7 x64 machine when I run without debugging, but is swallowed when I do.

Comment: @FacticiusVir: Exactly the same here. On my Win7 x64 it is swallowed only when I'm in the VS debugging mode.

Comment: There is an API that allows you to fix this. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11997142/119527) for how to use it in C#.