# Visual Studio does not break at exceptions in Form_Load Event

Tags: .net, visual-studio, exception, debugging

I recently updated my laptop from Vista 32bit with Visual Studio 2005/2008 installed to Windows 7 x64 with only Visual Studio 2008 installed. So I don't know if this is a "Windows 7" issue or just a configuration within visual studio.

My problem is that exeptions in the Form_Load() event get swallowed without notifing me, which  makes it harder to debug errors because sometimes I don't even notice that an exception occures.

Let's say I have this code (Code is VB.NET but commentary C# style, because the so-syntax highlighter doesn't recognize ' as a commentary sign)

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object,
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    // Outside the Debugger the exception triggers the default
    // "Unhandled Exception" Dialog which is correct.
    // Withing 2008 IDE the debugger doen not break like it
    // should. However the exception still occures because
    // this text is printed to the Output Window:
    // A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception'
    // occurred in ExceptionTest.exe
    Throw New Exception("This Exception gets swallowed")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    // This exception causes the Debugger to break at this line
    Throw New Exception("This Exception works fine")
End Sub

End Class
```

I found a suggestion to Check the "thrown" checkbox in the Exception Dialog ("CTRL+D,E").
If I do so the debugger breaks at the Form_Load() exception as I want it but it also breaks at every handled exception, e.g.:

```
Try
   DoSmthThatThrowsArgumentException() // Debugger breaks here
Catch ex as ArgumentException
   LogWriter.Write(ex.ToString())
End Try
```

Anyone has a clou how to configure VS2008 Debugger to behave right in the Form_Load() event? According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/netfx64bit/thread/e9c393df-9e49-41e9-b58a-914291fd0c45) it looks like that this is something that came suddenly with visual studio 2008.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583351/silent-failures-in-c-seemingly-unhandled-exceptions-that-does-not-crash-the-pro -- it's a x64 issue.  Voting as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the Link, I have searched stackoverflow (and almighty google of course) but did not find an explanation until now, thx.