# if statement with no result in C# VS 2012

Tags: c#, 64-bit, visual-studio-2012

I have a code like this in VS 2012:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default["Database"] != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("We landed on spot 1");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("We landed on spot 2");
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure I messed up the condition syntax, but I would expect that one of these would happen:

1. Compiler warns about errors/project fails to run.
2. First message is shown
3. Second message is shown.

But neither of these actually happens. I've been staring at this for an hour and resources I could find are pretty slim.
If anyone with an experience could explain me what actually happens here?

**Edit:**
Thanks to [JMK's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572995/how-can-i-get-winforms-to-stop-silently-ignoring-unhandled-exceptions) I found out this is basically a wontfix bug popping up in VS debugger under Windows x64. Error fires if application is run outside of debugger.

Comment: What _is_ actually happening?

Comment: put a debug point and see if you are getting into `Form1_Load`

Comment: Set a Breakpoint on the 1st if, i guess you will discover that your code is not running at all.

Comment: Try a MessageBox.Show("We landed on spot 0"); before the if statement to prove the Form1_Load event is firing

Comment: This is a well known bug in Windows Forms, the Load event runs asynchronously and exceptions are ignored - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572995/how-can-i-get-winforms-to-stop-silently-ignoring-unhandled-exceptions

Comment: Thanks JMK, that's it :) Thanks everyone for help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its silently erroring.

```
    try
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default["Database"] != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("We landed on spot 1");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("We landed on spot 2");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
    }
```

Comes back with "The settings property 'Database' was not found"

Comment: I tried it and was like wtf, so, added it and there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your project namespace before the `Properties`

```
if (WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings.Default.Database != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Propably an exception is thrown and not noticed by the debugger.
This happens for Windows Forms projects on 64bit Windows Versions (and is not a behaviour specific to .NET but to Windows in general).

More details here: [Visual Studio does not break at exceptions in Form_Load Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624156/visual-studio-does-not-break-at-exceptions-in-form-load-event)

Try pressing `STRG + ALT + E` and mark the checkbox "Thrown" for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".
Now the debugger will break on any exception in Form_Load()

Since I know about that my workaround is to completly avoid using the Load event.

Most of my Forms are Dialogs so I shadow the ShowDialog() method and call a Init() function.

```
public class Form1
{

    public new DialogResult ShowDialog()
    {
        Init();
        return base.ShowDialog();
    }

    public new DialogResult ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
    {
        Init();
        return base.ShowDialog(owner);
    }


    public void Init()
    {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```