# Visual Studio is not showing errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to read data from local database - sdf file. I am using this code to get it:

```
Private Sub BookEdit_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Using conn As New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|Library.sdf;Persist Security Info=False")

        conn.Open()

        Dim comm = New SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Book", conn)
        Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString(0))
        End While

    End Using

End Sub
```

When I open this form window, it is just freezing and then closing without showing any error.

> Tools -> Options->TextEditor->C#->

Here I have tried to turn on **Underline errors in the editor** and **Show live semantic errors**. However my code is in VB.net so when I open same thing for VB.NET there is no this function.

Also tried to turn on **Option Strict**

> Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VB defaults

But no effect. Visual Studio is not showing any error. So I do not know where to fix to connect to SDF file and show my windows form.

How to solve this problem?

Info:
Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate
Windows 8.1
Microsoft .NET framework 4.5.51641

Comment: move the code to a button click to test it - sometimes exceptions in FOrmLoad are hidden.  Or run in AnyCPU mode (but that disables edit and run).  `If reader.HasRows...` would not hurt either

Comment: what about constructor? can i put my code to constructor? will it catch error?

Comment: No, the earliest is Form_shown,  the button click is just to see catch the error; you could put it back once you fix it

Comment: `FormLoad` swallowing exceptions is an `x64` issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583351/silent-failures-in-c-seemingly-unhandled-exceptions-that-does-not-crash-the-pr

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying to help. And i guess you might have to close *conn* and *SqlCeDataReader* object as below code. Or further you might want to put the code in *Try-Catch* block.

```
Private Sub BookEdit_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Using conn As New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|Library.sdf;Persist Security Info=False")

    conn.Open()

    Dim comm = New SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Book", conn)
    Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader()

    While reader.Read()
        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString(0))
    End While

    reader.Close()
    conn.Close()
End Using
End Sub
```