# why does the instance method Controls.Find crash without an exception?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have this code in a form

The form is empty.

There is no button, so no button named b1.

This code crashes, but the strange thing is it gives no exception.

I know it crashes, because it doesn't reach that MessageBox.Show line.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  {

  Control[] controlsreturned = this.Controls.Find("b1", false);
  MessageBox.Show(controlsreturned.Length.ToString()); //0
  controlsreturned[0].ToString();  // intentional crash to demonstrate issue
  MessageBox.Show("reached here?"); // is not reached! but no exception thrown!

}
```

As a test, one could try adding  `Button b1 = new Button();  b1.Name = "b1";   this.Controls.Add(b1);`  and then it won't crash.

But my point is, why is it that when it crashes it doesn't throw an exception, it just crashes very silently. The program continues to run..  no exception is thrown. This is of course a slightly bigger inconvenience in a larger program as it makes it a bit more work to debug. But I use a small example to demonstrate.

Comment: This 'could' be related to [C# silently fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583351/silent-failures-in-c-seemingly-unhandled-exceptions-that-does-not-crash-the-pr?rq=1) but I don't know if this is an x64 issues.

Comment: @StephenRoss yeah you're right.  Interestingly I just tried wrapping it with a try catch and it caught /detected the exception

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. It's not silent at all but [breaking very load](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160523/ib9modaf.jpg).

Comment: @TimSchmelter If this is the x64 issue you'll have to make sure you're building in x64 for this to occur as it seems to be a Kernal issue.

Comment: @StephenRoss: still the same exception (shown in m link above)