# C# winforms doesn't catch exceptions in specific cases

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

Trying to ask my question again - last time it messed up.

This is my example code:

1. Little form, that contains only button and combobox:

   ```
   public partial class question : Form
   {
   public question()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       comboBox1.DataSource = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
   }

   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("In comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged");
       throw new Exception();
   }
   }
   ```
2. Project's `Program` class that calls the `question` form and handles the exceptions:

   ```
    class Program
   {
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       try
       {
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

           // Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
           Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod);

           // Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through
           // our handler.
           Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

           // Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
           AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
               new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

           Application.Run(new question());
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "3");
       }
   }
   private static void MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs t)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.Message + "1");
   }

   private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message + "2");
   }
   }
   ```

Now, when one clicks the button, the event "SelectedIndexChanged" is rise (and the messageBox appear) **but** the exception is ignored. Only when the user selects manually another index in the combobox, the exception handled.

The question is, how to handle these exceptions too?

Comment: Let me get this right. Your console based application and winForm are two separate applications and you want to run the winFrom application from console based application - is that right?

Comment: @YawarMurtaza thanks. Isn't two separated application. It's just that the Main of the application is console application (actually is always like that). Not really matter.

Comment: Okay - I have created the exact copy of your code. The runtime never reaches " Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "3");" statement no matter what is done in the winForm. There must be something to do with Application.Run() method, it creates a new message loop for the winForm application on the same thread on which the Main method runs. Let me see if I can find how the exceptions are handelled in this case.

Comment: It seems like an old exception handling problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583351/silent-failures-in-c-seemingly-unhandled-exceptions-that-does-not-crash-the-pr

Answer (score 4):

could not intercept exception even with try-catch:

```
try
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c"};
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

It seems ComboBox ignores exceptions which happen when DataSource is set:

[ListControl.DataSource source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,9b4ddb1c1478bf7b)

```
try 
{
    SetDataConnection(value, displayMember, false);
} catch 
{
    DisplayMember = "";
}
```

[ComboBox.DataSource uses base ListControl implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,88d2575e9db1ebea)