# Datagridview cell turns black when accessing EditedFormattedValue?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a winforms application that uses a datagridview.  When I access the EditedFormattedValue of a cell while it is in edit mode, sometimes the whole cell turns black.  Is this a feature of the datagridview, perhaps some sort of validation feature I need to turn off?

I have found a couple of other mentions of this problem while googling.  None of the threads seem to know what the answer is either:

Here not calling Application.DoEvents solved the problem, but I am not calling DoEvents.
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1277303&page=1

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdatacontrols/thread/d9bf784d-617d-4a35-8125-fe8f67987fa2
Here no one knew why it was happening, but responders suggest setting the background color to white.  That seems like a hack, and I'd like to know why this is happening.  Also, changing the background color doesn't remove the black background for me.

**Added by barlop**

[image]

Note there is another cause of this, but since the title here is editedformattedvalue, i'll note this example first.

**Example involving EditedFormattedValue as cause.**

(when you double click the cell, (thus going into edit mode), it goes black)

```
namespace simpleblackdgv2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // BUG IS THAT WHEN YOU DOUBLE CLICK A CELL, IT GOES BLACK


            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column1");

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);

            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;


            this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);


            dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;

        }

        private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {

            // doesn't work
             string str = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();



        }


        }
    }
```

On a related note this is another example of it going black, though not from editedformattedvalue   (A previous edit to this question has a longer example, this is a simpler one that cuts to it quicker). The bug shows an issue when the general autosize settings are on  - set to allcells, and a specific one is set to None, then it can get buggy depending on how you order the statements, which must be a bug.  When setting any specific autosize, set the general to off.

**Example Black related to resizing**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace blackdgvcellexample {

public partial class Form1 : Form {

    DataGridView dataGridView1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // autosize rows may be meaningless without that.
        //dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column1");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column2", "Column2");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column3", "Column3");

        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;


         dataGridView1.Rows.Add(5);
        //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);

        dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;


    }


    private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {



        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;


        //dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells; //A
        // dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells; //B
        // dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; //C

        // B-Cols, C-rows
        // A, ~B, ~C  WORKS
        // A,B, ~C  WORKS
        // A,~B,C  WORKS
        // A,B,C   WORKS
        // SO IT WAS THE ORDER OF THE LINES THAT MAKES A DIFFERENCE!!!!


        // --- trying not turning any off
        //            dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells; //A
        //           dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells; //B        
        //            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; //C

        // Cols, Rows, A  BLACK FIRST CELL REST FINE
        // rows, Cols, A   BLACK FIRST CELL REST FINE
        // cols,A,rows   FINE
        // rows,A,cols  BLACK FIRST CELL REST FINE
        // A, rows, cols   BLACK FIRST CELL
        // A, cols, rows  FINE

        // perhaps unnecessary to autoaize rows. 

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells; //A

        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; 
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells; 


        // this works
        /*
```

dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells; //A
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; 
*/

```
        /* 
         * this works
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells; //A            
        */

        /*
          doesn't work
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells; //A            
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells; 
          */

        // doesn't work
        //   dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        //   dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells; //A            

        // so don't mix them. ok

        // this doesn't work

        //            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
        //          dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells; //A            


        // these 3 work in any order
        //  dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
        //  dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
        //  dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells; //A            

        // don't mix them. 
        // if you are going to mix them, then turn the generals off and do specifics.
        // this won't work
        //  dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        //  dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        //  dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None; //A            

        // this works, probably any order too.
        /*
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;           
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;           
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        */


    }



}


}
```

related- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2878864/datagridview-cell-goes-black

Comment: note that in the column resizing example it can  be avoided by shrinking the whole thing (or by figuring out why it happens when just one col and solving that though haven't found the answer to that yet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, though I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening with the `str=dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue`, I found that using the `str=dataGridView1.EditingControl.Text` value gets the same value and doesn't mess with the cell formatting.  So, I guess that solves my problem.

Comment: Didn't solve my problem, but I probably have a couple sources of this symptom.

Comment: Actually this did solve my problem for text boxes and combo boxes (had to do something similar for setting the cell (note: have to check if the cell is in edit mode in get and set), but then if I set the value on an image cell I still get the black box :(

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem in a C# WinForms application and changing to use EditingControl.Text fixed my problem as well.

Comment: I found your solution worked for me. But then another time even with this solution I had the problem and I ran into some other cause to do with having some columns autosized and others not.. resolved by making them all autosized or all shrunk rather than specifying individual ones. I mention that in a comment within the code to an answer I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686309/datagridview-change-edit-control-size-while-editing/38112993#38112993 dated 30th june 2016  I guess it might be a bug in datagridview that we're working around

Comment: I found your solution worked for me. But then another time even with this solution I had the problem and I ran into some other cause to do with having some columns autosized and others not.. resolved by making them all autosized or all shrunk rather than specifying individual ones. I mention that in an answer I posted here(and I mention it within a `/* ..*/` within the code in that answer   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686309/datagridview-change-edit-control-size-while-editing/38112993#38112993   dated 30th june 2016 I guess it might be a bug in datagridview that we're working around.

Comment: @micahhoover try my answer

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and could also not figure out why.

I had this code in my EditingControlShowing because for some reason, this cell would always capitalize the contents when editing even with `CharacterCasing` set to Normal. This was my workaround:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl control1 = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;    
control1.Text = dataGridView1C.CurrentCell.FormattedValue.ToString();
```

And the solution was to change that last line of code to this:

```
control1.Text = dataGridView1C.EditingControl.Text;
```

There aren't many discussons on this issue and I'm suprised it's still around in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is now mentioned here

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2878864/datagridview-cell-goes-black

Besides the workaround mentioned by dvcolgan that works just for the case of editedformattedvalue.

There is a workaround from viorel mentioned at the ms bug link, that i've tested and works, which is to surround the code with

```
 BeginInvoke( new Action( ( ) =>
     {
        . . .
     } ) );
```

The above BeginInvoke technique works for both cases.