# How can I dynamically detect the characters in a DataGridView cell? / Execute code after KeyDown returns and before KeyUp?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, keydown

How can I dynamically detect the characters in a DataGridView cell(while it is being edited)?

For example,

I have a Winforms application with a DataGridView and a TextBox

```
        private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control is TextBox)
            {
                var tbox = (e.Control as TextBox);

                // De-register the event FIRST so as to avoid multiple assignments (necessary to do this or the event
                // will be called +1 more time each time it's called).
                tbox.KeyDown -= DGV_TextBoxKeyDown;
                tbox.KeyDown += DGV_TextBoxKeyDown;

            }
        }

        private void DGV_TextBoxKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();

        }
```

The code I have is one character late, so for example if I type abcde, then the textbox displays abcd. I want it to display abcde (I don't want it to be one character late)

[image]

But I don't want to do it by appending the key that was pushed, because if I type abcde and delete the 'b' then I want the textbox to show it's acde. So I want to be able to read the current value(the value after the key has been pushed down), (and before the key has been pushed up), but I can't see how

Notice how the textbox is out of date.
, and likewise below, it's out of date,  I type abcde and delete the 'b'. It is only getting the old edited value from before the key was pushed down.

I don't want to do it on key up because if for example a key is held for e.g. 10 seconds and lifted, then there would be a 10 seconds delay before the textbox will be updated. I really want it such that any time a character is typed, the textbox updates.

I know that if a key is held, then keydown executes multiple times. If I was able to execute code after KeyDown returns, and before KeyUp, then I could check `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();` then, and that should do it.  But I don't know how.

[image]

Comment: Try using the keypress method instead of key down

Comment: @Shon no that does not work, it is delayed by one. you can try it and you'd see

Comment: Why don't you try with `tbox.TextChanged` event handler and just update the text in the other textbox each time the text has been changed?

Comment: @D.Petrov thanks, I hadn't tried tbox.TextChanged. that works, you can post that as an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the suspicion that there could be anything that makes it not that simple, but after all you could just use the `.TextChanged` event with the textbox in the DGV and update the value of the other TextBox on each change.